# Dynamic Popup Dropdown Form Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu

I have a list of items in the Summary tab of my spreadhseet, this list changes relatively frequelty but the number of options is limited to 17, some of which may be null at times. I would like to have the available options(non null) be put into a popup with a dropdown list. This value would then be input into a specific cell (call it Summary C55 for now).

I think my GS code is sound, I'm getting lost on the HTML component. Lists are coming up without any options.

## .GS

```
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
  //available characters found in P2:P18 of Summary tab
  var options=[];
  var va=sheet.getRange("P2:P18").getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<va.length;i++){
  options.push(va[i][0]);
  Logger.log(options);
}
  return options; // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}  

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('popup').setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select your new character');
}
function select(){
   var menu= SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu');
      menu.addItem('Dropdown Form', 'showDialog');
      menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen(e){
select();
}
```

## popup.HTML

[image: html]

[image: popup]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    function loadCharacters() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(makeoptions) 
    .getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
    }
       function makeoptions(ar){
        var charselect = document.createElementById('character');
        console.log(ar);
        for (var i=0;i<ar.length;i++);
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = ar[i]
        option.id = ar[i];
        charselect.appendChild(option);
  };
  function selected() {
    var value = document.getElementById('character').value;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=value;
    console.log(value);
  };
</script>
<html>
 <head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
  <body onload="loadCharacters()">
  <form id="Form">
    <div>
       <label for="List"> Select Character </label><br>
        <input list="character" name="charselect">
        <datalist id= "character"></datalist>
        <select id="character" onchange="selected()"> </select><br>
    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I ask you whether your current script in your question works except for `I would like to have the available options(non null) be put into a popup with a dropdown list.`?

Comment: If you bind this code to your Spreadsheet, there won't be a "document" Object because it runs in the backend. Can you please show what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Tanaike the script runs. function getValuesFromSpreadsheet()  returns [Brute, Spellweaver, Mindthief, Scoundrel, Craigheart, Tinkerer, , , , Berserker, , , , , , , ] to the log. The popup shows up with no options inside. Additionally, I can't seem to make my check in the HTML work at all. I see errors in the console showing blocked activities.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your current situation is correct. From your replying, I understood that in your script, Google Apps Script side works, but HTML&Javascript side doesn't work. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect it. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a SELECT control instead of getting the one that already exists on the HTML. Try changing the following line from:

`var charselect = document.createElementById('character');`

To:

`var charselect = document.getElementById('character');`

Since there are two elements with the same ID, you should probably delete this:

`<datalist id= "character"></datalist>`

Also, you'll need to include the inner HTML of each option (before appending the child to the SELECT) to show the available character name:

`option.innerHTML = ar[i];`

---

**Update:**

I realized that the For loop didn't have anything inside it, so it needs to be changed as well:

```
function makeoptions(ar) {
  var charselect = document.getElementById('character');
  console.log(ar);
  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = ar[i];
    option.id = ar[i];
    option.innerHTML = ar[i];
    charselect.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

Other than that, some other parts of the HTML needs to be updated as well, such as the *select* function:

```
function selected() {
  var value = document.getElementById('character').value;
  document.getElementById('value').value = value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

And the ID attribute was missing from the input control:
`<input list="character" name="charselect" id='value'/>`

> This value would then be input into a specific cell (call it Summary C55 for now).

As for writing the selection back to the spreadsheet, you can add this to the end of the select *function*: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(selectionWritten).writeSelection(value);`.

And you can have something like the following to confirm the operation on the HTML:

```
function selectionWritten() {
  console.log('selection written to spreadsheet');
}
```

Then you include something like this on the Apps Script side:

```
function writeSelection(value){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Summary");
  sheet.getRange('C55').setValue(value);
}
```

From what I tried, it seems to work with these additional changes.

Comment: This was very helpful. It's about 90% of the way there but for some reason it's only populating thelast item on the list.